# How to align array plot and graph plot?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I would like to combine a MatrixPlot and a GraphPlot, but I can't find a way to align them.

The code is

```
M = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];
G = GridGraph[{5, 5}];

SetOptions[MatrixPlot, DataReversed -> True];

Show[MatrixPlot[M], GraphPlot[G]]
```

And the output displays the graph G with its origin in {1,1},
whereas the origin of the matrix is in {0,0}.

[image: Two graphs combined, but displaced]

How can I align the origin of both graphics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, but note that the graph is re-made (with translated vertices.)

```
SeedRandom[123];
M = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];
G = GridGraph[{5, 5}];
vcs = Map[# - {1, 1} &, 
   VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[G, VertexCoordinates]];
G = GridGraph[{5, 5}, VertexCoordinates -> vcs];

SetOptions[MatrixPlot, DataReversed -> True]; 
Show[MatrixPlot[M], GraphPlot[G]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `VertexCoordinates` option:

```
mM = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {4, 4}]
mG = GridGraph[{5, 5}, VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range[5] - 1, 2]]
Show[MatrixPlot[mM, DataReversed -> True], GraphPlot[mG]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**`VertexCoordinateRules` set to `TranslationTransform` of `GraphEmbedding[G]`:**

```
mp1 = MatrixPlot[M, DataReversed -> True, ImageSize -> 300,  Epilog -> 
 GraphPlot[G, VertexCoordinateRules -> 
     TranslationTransform[{-1, -1}] @ GraphEmbedding[G]][[1]]];
```

**`TranslationTransform` on `Show[G]`:**

```
mp2 = MatrixPlot[M, DataReversed -> True,  ImageSize -> 300, Epilog -> 
  MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, TranslationTransform[{-1, -1}]] &, Show[G], {1}][[1]]];
```

**`VertexCoordinates` set to `TranslationTransform` of `GraphEmbedding[G]`:**

```
G2 = Show[SetProperty[G, { VertexStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0.7], VertexSize -> .05, 
     EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], RGBColor[0.5, 0., 0.]], 
     VertexCoordinates -> TranslationTransform[{-1, -1}] @ GraphEmbedding[G]}]][[1]];
mp3 = MatrixPlot[M, DataReversed -> True, ImageSize -> 300,  Epilog -> G2];

Row[{mp1, mp2, mp3}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html)?

```
SeedRandom[7]

M = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];
G = GridGraph[{5, 5}];

SetOptions[MatrixPlot
  , DataReversed -> True
  , DataRange -> {{1.5, 4.5}, {1.5, 4.5}}
  , FrameTicks -> Range@{5, 5, 5, 5}
];

Show[MatrixPlot[M], GraphPlot[G]]
```

[image]